# Sometimes test fails with message ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

Tags: c#

I have unit tests that fail with the message: **ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed**, when all the unit tests are run but succeed when being run individually.
The place they both fail looks like this:

```
public void Handle()
{
   using (ConnectionManager.Open())
   {
      var result = Query().ToList();
   }
}
```

Query looks something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Thing> Query()
{
  // Create parameters and stored proc name ...

  return Connection.Query(storedProcedureName, parameters);
}
```

Stepping through the code shows that the Connection is open before entering the query, but closed when entering it. However when run individually the connection remains open until the end of the using and succeeds.
I have no idea why this is the case. I was thinking maybe the tests were being run asynchronously and trying to access the same connection in the connection pool but when debugging they do seem to execute synchronously.

**Edit:This is what the failing tests look like**

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CanDoThings()
    {
        // Arrange            
        var before = _repository.Query().ToList();

        var command = new Command();

        // Act
        CommandHandler().Handle(command); // Throws error in here

        // Assert
        var after = _repository.Query().ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error might be suppressed by wrapping your _repository in a using statement

The code block below requires an instantiated and open `Connection`

```
var result = Query().ToList();
```

Due to Lazy Loading, the code above is only evaluated after it has been acted upon in the block below (outside of the connections using statement scope).

```
var before = _repository.Query().ToList();
```

Since you initialized the `connection` in the using clause, the scope has left and you do not know if the Connection has been disposed. I would try wrapping every repository method with a using statement similar to below.

Or you would need to iterate all the items in the collection (.ToList()) inside your using to get predictable results.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanDoThings()
{
    using (_repository=new MyRepository())
    {
        // Arrange            
        var before = _repository.Query().ToList();

        var command = new Command();

        // Act
        CommandHandler().Handle(command); // Throws error in here

        // Assert
        var after = _repository.Query().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, still happening. I should probably have mentioned that each test is run inside of a transaction scope so that I could roll back the db when done.

Comment: I fixed it. Sort of. I stopped the error from happening but it just means there are other problems but everything is working now. You were sort of right. I needed to create a new instance of my repository for each test instead of recycling.